# 1980s teen sci-fi film where a group of kids have a large dog that transforms into a giant beast at the end

Tags: story-identification, movie

A long time ago I watched a movie which at the end has a big twist whereby the bunch of kids we’ve followed through the film have a dog which metamorphoses into a large beast and combats another large beast alien to save the kids.

I seem to remember that it was set in the U.S. and perhaps an 80s film set in the 80s too, very similar to *Stand by Me* (1986) in its appearance, cinematography, and film stock, but with this big twist of being an sci-fi alien film only found out in the closing minutes in a battle scene by a lake when the kid protagonists are attacked by an alien.

---

It was not *I Am Number 4* (2011).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The dog doesn't transform, and there's only the one kid, but perhaps [*Watchers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watchers_(film)) (1988)?

About a boy who befriends an intelligent dog that has a link to a monster on the loose.  The dog helps the boy fight the monster.